# Django determine if signals are necessary

Tags: python, django, signals

Signals are a very useful part of Django, But I am having a hard time figuring out when they are really necessary. Take the following ambiguous example:

```
class FooBar(models.Model):
    some_field = models.something(#...)

    def func(self):
        # do something
        signals.some_signal.send(#...)
```

so this will send a signal whenever the `func` method is called. But one could also do the following:

```
def func(self):
    # do something
    # do what was in the receiver function
```

Are there any classifications of when to use a signal, and when to just include it in the original location?

It seems as though most situations will work both ways. Are signals just more optimal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea behind signals or events is that some source generates them and someone else consumes them **without knowing about each other**.

So while your example does work technically, it creates a hard dependency between `func()` and the receiver function. If the receiver goes away or changes, you always need to check `func()` as well.

With signals, `func()` just publishes a signal. Whoever might be interested (and there might be dozens of receivers or none) gets a notification without any change to `func()`.